# AsyncDisplayKit aka Texture v/s UIKit. Which is better and Why? - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have read about pros and cons of AsyncDisplayKit and UIKit. But I am still not sure that which one I should opt out. In my scenario, I have to create a view having collection view inside table view with so many images, videos and audios and action on them. Please help.